# Running a list command strings with subprocess popen and getting the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run multiple UNIX commands in a python script like this

```
import subprocess


cmds = ['sleep 3', 'uptime','time ls -l /']


p = subprocess.Popen(cmds,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)


while p.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)


tempdata = p.stdout.read()



print(tempdata)
```

However my output does not contain all output and doesn't seem to run all the commands. Setting shell=False also causes an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task1.py", line 32, in ?
    p = subprocess.Popen(commands,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python36/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python36/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new process, you don't pass it a list of commands to run; rather, you pass it a **single command** -- either as a string (with `shell=True`) or as a list of args (with `shell=False`).

```
import subprocess

cmds = ['sleep 1', 'uptime', 'ls -l /']

for cmd in cmds:
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    print('\n# {}'.format(cmd))
    print(stdout)
```

If you just want to collect stdout, `subprocess.check_output()` might be simpler than `Popen()` -- but either approach will work, depending on what you need to do with the process.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is 'sleep 3' causes the error you get from the traceback, when I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To run all for these:

```
cmds = ['sleep 3', 'uptime','time ls -l /']
```

You have to call popen for each of them:

```
for cmd in cmds:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.5)

    output = p.stdout.read()
```

Or simpler:

```
for cmd in cmds:
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Second question: This captures all output written to stdout. To capture also stderr, redirect that into `subprocess.PIPE` as well.